# Task status not changing to Cancelled when in the middle of execution

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

I was reading a book on [Parallel Programming](http://parallel%20patterns.codeplex.com) and I coded the following scenario which worked as expected (Task.Status == TaskStatus.Canceled):

> It’s possible for a task to end in TaskStatus.Canceled. For this
>   to occur, you must pass a CancellationToken as an argument to the
>   factory method that created the task. If that token signals a request
>   for cancellation *before* the task begins to execute, the task won’t be
>   allowed to run. The task’s Status property will transition directly to
>   TaskStatus.Canceled without ever invoking the task’s user delegate.

But I couldn't get expected result (Task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled) for the following:

> If the token signals a cancellation request *after* the task begins to
>   execute, the task’s Status property will only transition to
>   TaskStatus.Canceled if the user delegate throws an Operation
>   CanceledException and that exception’s CancellationToken property
>   contains the token that was given when the task was created.

**Code**

```
  public void DoWork(int millisec, CancellationToken token, int n )
    {
        ParallelOptions option = new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = token };

        Parallel.For(0, n, option, (i) =>
        {
           // Thread.Sleep(millisec);
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        });
    }

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
   CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

   t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(700, token, 99999999), token);
   t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(5, token, 1), token);

   Task[] tasks = new Task[] { t1,t2 };

   int completedTaskIndex = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
   lblMsg.Text = "Task No." + ++completedTaskIndex + " has been completed.\n";

   cts.Cancel();
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Updated
   lblMsg.Text += "Rest of the tasks have been cancelled.\n";

   try
   {
       lblMsg.Text += "Task 1 Status: " + t1.Status + "\n";
       lblMsg.Text += "Task 2 Status: " + t2.Status + "\n";

       Task.WaitAll(tasks);
       lblMsg.Text += "No exceptions has been reported yet.\n";
   }
   catch(AggregateException ae)
   {

           ae.Flatten().Handle((ex) =>
           {
          // if you debug to see the token handle it is the same as passed to Task.Factory.StartNew()
               if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
           {
               CancellationToken tok = ((OperationCanceledException)ex).CancellationToken;
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
       );
   }
   finally 
   {
     if(cts!= null)  
         cts.Dispose();

     cts = null;
   }
}
```

**Result**

Before Update:

[image]

After Update:

[image]

**Dicussion**

Task 1 is the task which is cancelled so its Status should have been Cancelled instead of Running as shown in figure above.

**Question**

Is there any understanding gap that I could not get desired result? Where did i lose the track?

**Updated (Issue Resolved)**

The problem was that I was reading the status of task 1 before it was updated to Cancelled. So I wrote Thread.Sleep(5000); just after cts.Cancel(); so that there's enough time for the task to be cancelled and the status be updated appropriately. That let the status of task 1 to show "Cancelled".

Comment: How did `lblMsg.Text += "Task 1 Status: " + t1.Status + "\n";` generate a label text of "... before wait..." ?

Comment: You may have issued the cancel but task 1 is probably still in its `Sleep`. It hasn't woken up yet to observe the changed state of the token.

Comment: And also, when did task 1 get any time to process its cancellation in between cancel being invoked (while it was sleeping?) and its status being read? Maybe you should read the status at the end of the code, or at least after WaitAll ?

Comment: Thread.Sleep() seemed like a bone of contention so I have commented it out. And changed the loop argument passed in Task. Now task-1 has to loop 50000 times while task 2 has to loop just once. Still Status of Task-1 is Running

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the program flow, in comments, assuming it takes 1ms to process each line:

```
   int completedTaskIndex = Task.WaitAny(tasks); //Time T=0
   lblMsg.Text = "Task No." + ++completedTaskIndex + " has been completed.\n"; //time T=5, because we waited 5ms for task 2, right?

   cts.Cancel(); //Time T=6, task 1 is sleeping for another 694 ms
   lblMsg.Text += "Rest of the tasks have been cancelled.\n"; //Time T=7

   try
   {
       lblMsg.Text += "Task 1 Status: " + t1.Status + "\n";//Time T = 8, task1 is sleeping for another 692 ms, current status is "running"
       lblMsg.Text += "Task 2 Status: " + t2.Status + "\n";//Time T=9

       Task.WaitAll(tasks);//Time T=701, task 1 has finished sleeping, and finds out it is cancelled
       lblMsg.Text += "No exceptions has been reported yet.\n";//we probably don't hit this line/see it in label, because cancellation exception is thrown by task 1
   }
   catch(AggregateException ae) //what's task1's status now?
```

Ultimately I think this is one fo those cases where if you'd jsut coded up the real world task, the UI that has a "go" button that changes to "cancel" before you start your thousand db queries or whatever, then things would have worked out.. but this artificial test you've arranged isn't really representative of the real life cancellation scenario

Comment: I have commented out Thread.Sleep(). Please go through my edited version. Still task-1 is in Running state

Comment: It's not really what I was advising

Comment: I understand the fact that while sleeping, thread could not entertain any cancellation request but as soon as the sleep time elapse it does qualify  for cancellation and hence caught in the Catch block.Nevertheless, in both the cases, with or without Thread.Sleep(), the cancelled task in the middle of running state maintains its status to "Running" even after being cancelled. When the status should have been "Cancelled".

Comment: I still think with the code as you have it, the job is running when its status is checked, you note in the label text that it is running, and then you never check again or update the label text after that...

Comment: Status could be checked only before Task.Wait() - and that is what i have already done in the code. However, could not check after that because due to Cancellation exception lines of codes written after Task.Wait() would never execute. Suggest me where else could I update the label?

Comment: But that's the thing - let's say you have a long running database query that after 30seconds gives an error. If you check its status after 1 second and store it in a label as "status:ok" then 29 seconds later it explodes, you can't come complaining "the label says it's fine but it clearly blew up.." - the system told you the truth at the time it was asked?!

Comment: Thanks got it! Your example actually helped me understand that.